# Improve neon sharped cut text effect

Tags: html, css, svg, filter, svg-filters

I am trying to add sharped cut effect on text. I have achieved this thing:
[image]
But I want to achieve this backplate/background sharped cut text effect:
[image]

**My Code:**

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #000;
}
.previewText {
    text-shadow: var(--text-color) 0px 0px 10px, var(--text-color) 0px 0px 25px, #000 1px 1px 1px;
    --text-color: #fff;
}
.previewText svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="preview-items--item__text previewText cut-sharp" style="font-family: Amarila; font-size: 50px; --text-color:#30cbfd;">
   <div style="filter: url(&quot;#cutSharpru5i2bye4iml4tvt6s0&quot;);">
      <p>work <span style="font-family: PoiretOne;">HARD</span></p>
      <p><span style="font-family: PoiretOne;">dream</span> big</p>
   </div>
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <filter id="cutSharpru5i2bye4iml4tvt6s0">
         <feMorphology in="SourceGraphic" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2.5"></feMorphology>
         <feFlood flood-color="#fff" flood-opacity="0.12" result="neon"></feFlood>
         <feComposite in="neon" in2="dilated" operator="in" result="cutSharpru5i2bye4iml4tvt6s0"></feComposite>
         <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="cutSharpru5i2bye4iml4tvt6s0"></feMergeNode>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
         </feMerge>
      </filter>
   </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to achieve that thing as shown in the image #2? I am stuck. I tried a lot but i just got a little bit of a stroke with `svg`, the stroke should be in the full background of texts as shown in the image #2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use lighting primitives to get those edge lighting effects. Lighting primitives are buggy and usually trigger some kind of weird cross-browser bug then when you try to run them on Safari. Even Chrome runs into issues with them because they're just not very well debugged.

That caveat provided - this is the basic structure of how you'd accomplish something like this. It's a painstaking process of trial and error to figure out the exact right combination of lighting effect attributes to get exactly what you want - so this is something in the right neighborhood but I would not claim this is professional quality yet.

I would probably recommend Photoshop rather than SVG filters for this kind of effect.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}


.meow {
  font-family: 'Meow Script', cursive;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: light;
  fill: #faf;
  stroke: none;
}

.comfort {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: light;
  fill: #FAF;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Meow+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
      <filter id="shiny-filter"  height="200%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <!-- Part 1 neon text -->
        <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="0.25" result="dilated-original"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.75"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                             0 1 0 0 0 
                                             0 0 1 0 0 
                                             0 0 0 1.1 0"
                       result="glow"/>
         <feComposite operator="over" in2='SourceGraphic' result="neon-text"/>
        
         <!-- Part 2 drop shadow -->
         <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" in="dilated-original" result="blurred-dil-orig"/>
         <feFlood flood-color="#111"/>
         <feComposite operator="in" in2="blurred-dil-orig"/>
         <feOffset dy="4" result="drop-shadow-y"/>
        <feComposite operator="over" in="neon-text" in2="drop-shadow-y" result="neon-text-and-shadow"/>
        
         <!-- Part 3 backplate --> 
        <feMorphology radius="2" operator="dilate" in="dilated-original" result="super-dilated-original"/>
        <feFlood x="9.5" y="4" width="72" height="30" flood-color="#111"/>
        <feComposite operator="over" in="super-dilated-original"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="combined-backdrop"/>
        <feFlood flood-color="#222"/>
        <feComposite operator="in" in2="combined-backdrop" result="combined-backdrop-grey"/>
        
        <!-- Part 4 lighting --> 
       <feSpecularLighting in="combined-backdrop-grey" result="topOut" specularExponent="15" lighting-color="#FcF" surfaceScale="2">
       <fePointLight x="50" y="-150" z="10"/>
       </feSpecularLighting>
      
        
      <feSpecularLighting  in="combined-backdrop-grey" result="leftOut" specularExponent="15" lighting-color="#FcF" surfaceScale="2" >
       <fePointLight x="-150" y="50" z="10"/>
       </feSpecularLighting>
        
      <feSpecularLighting in="combined-backdrop-grey" result="rightOut" specularExponent="15" lighting-color="#FcF" surfaceScale="2" >
       <fePointLight x="150" y="50" z="10"/>
       </feSpecularLighting>

       <feMerge>
         <feMergeNode in="combined-backdrop-grey"/>
         <feMergeNode in="neon-text-and-shadow"/>
         <feMergeNode in="leftOut"/>
         <feMergeNode in="topOut"/>
         <feMergeNode in="rightOut"/>
        </feMerge>
        
        
        
      </filter>
    
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0 3)" filter="url(#shiny-filter)">
  <text class="meow" x="10" y="11">work</text>
    <text class="comfort" x="38" y="14">HARD</text>
    <text class="comfort" x="9" y="33">DREAM</text>
    <text class="meow" x="73" y="33">big</text>
</g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Bro, I need the text in the div, not in the svg.

Comment: Lighting primitives don't work in CSS Filters in Safari Bro. If you want cross browser you have to do pure SVG.

Comment: I am not familiar much with custom svgs, that's why it's difficult for me to customize it. The svg you created, taking a lot of space, and when i try to reduce the size like 100px width, it doesn't work fine: https://snipboard.io/OE7N53.jpg, + if you can notice, there is a white light outside: https://snipboard.io/VINjz9.jpg